# Asp .Net Core Json deserialize to model

Tags: json, asp.net-core, dynamic, jsonconvert, dynamic-properties

Returns Json format data to me from an api.

However, the type of the "FuelType" property inside the object may be different. For example, 1 time comes as follows:

```
{
...
fuelType: "gasoline"
...
}}
```

But then it can happen:

```
{
...
fuelType: ["gasoline", "any"]
...
}}
```

If I set the "FuelType" property type on my model to a string, in the second case, Json will give me an error when it arrives, because it can't convert from array to string. No, if I set the type to an array, then, conversely, if a string arrives, it will issue an error because it cannot convert from a string to an array.

In this case, what should I put the "FuelType" property type in my model so that it does not make an error when deserializing?

Comment: If it can return a array...Jut make it an array?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var fuelType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("fuelType")]
    private JToken _fuelType;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string[] fuelType
    {
        get {
if (_fuelType==null) return null;
 return _fuelType is JArray ? _fuelType.ToObject<string[]>() : new string[] { (string)_fuelType }; }
        set { _fuelType = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: _fueltype fieldi but comes null. Can you help with that?

Comment: The field still remains at null value. I think that's why it's null. ( Code image link : https://imgur.com/B8YV0XB )

Comment: @Elchin It is just a warning. Do you have any bugs when you are deserializing a json?

Comment: No. Everything except FuelType is properly deserialized

Comment: This code was tested in visual studio and working properly. Can you post your json that can not be deserialized?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on you,what type of value you want to receive?string or List?

I tried with the codes:

```
public class SomeModel
    {
        public SomeModel()
        {
            fuelType = new List<string>();            
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        
        public List<string> fuelType { get; set; }

        //you could move the codes to someservice
        public List<string> someresult(string a)
        {
            var targetlist = new List<string>();
            targetlist.Add(a);
            return targetlist;
        }
        public List<string> someresult(List<string> a)
        {
            var targetlist = new List<string>();
            targetlist.AddRange(a);
            return targetlist;
        }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SomeAction()
        {
            var somemodel = new SomeModel() { Id = 1, Name = "name" };
            var somevalue = /*"a"*/new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
            var targetvalue = somemodel.someresult(somevalue);
            somemodel.fuelType.AddRange(targetvalue);
            return new JsonResult(somemodel);
        }
```

Result:
[image]